# How to list all products from API with curl command line?

Tags: magento2, api, json, curl

I've been trying a lot of things and can't seem to figure out what should be pretty simple... How can I make a request with curl **in command line** to /index.php/rest/V1/products so that I simply get the list of all products?

Everything I tried got me this error:

```
{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"searchCriteria"}}
```

If I start from this, what should I add?

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be enough

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria"
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using below code to get product list from third party API. But we are not doing it using command line, we have written curl code to get response. Hope this will also help you.

```
$curl     = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL            => "YOUR API URL",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 50,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => "{\n\"user\":\"$username\",\n\"pwd\":\"$password\",\n\"DS\":\"$ds\"\n}",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
        "postman-token: 26e3f35f-8c91-4c29-e690-ddbc42e62755"
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err      = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

There we go:

```
curl -g -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like"
```